# php node into multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is a script I got so far.

```
<?php 

 $xml= simplexml_load_file("http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/observ/surface/text/sl/observationAms_si_latest.xml");
  // print_r($xml);

$meteos = $xml->metData; 

$spot = array();
foreach ($meteos as $meteo) {
$spot[] = "$meteo->domain_title, $meteo->tsValid_issued, $meteo->t, $meteo->dd_icon, $meteo->ff_val, $meteo->ffmax_val, $meteo->msl, $meteo->rr_val, $meteo->rr_val";

}

print_r($spot);

    ?>
```

What I get with this is something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BILJE NOVA GORICA, 31.08.2013 21:00 CEST, 19.2, E, 1.5, 1.8, 1019, 0, 0
    [1] => BOHINJSKA CESNJICA, 31.08.2013 21:00 CEST, 14.4, , , , , , 
    [2] => BORST GORENJA VAS, 31.08.2013 21:00 CEST, 15.3, SW, 0.4, 1.3, 1020, 0, 0
```

what I would like to get is

```
Array
(
    [0] => BILJE NOVA GORICA
          [0] => 31.08.2013 21:00 CEST
          [1] =>19.2 
          [2] =>E
          [3] =>1.5
          [4] =>1.8 
          [5] =>1019
```

How do I do that? Also I would like to find an array that contains "ILIRSKA BISTRICA" so I can write it to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do it like that, however you have 2 alternatives:

```
Array
(
    [BILJE NOVA GORICA]  => Array
    (
        [0] => 31.08.2013 21:00 CEST
        [1] =>19.2 
        ....
    )
)
```

Or

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => BILJE NOVA GORICA
        [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31.08.2013 21:00 CEST
            [1] =>19.2 
            ...
        )
    )
)
```

I would recommend the first method as it's smaller and easier to work with. You can set your array up like that by simply doing:

```
$spot[$meteo->domain_title] = array(
    $meteo->tsValid_issued,
    $meteo->t,
    $meteo->dd_icon,
    $meteo->ff_val,
    $meteo->ffmax_val,
    $meteo->msl,
    $meteo->rr_val,
    $meteo->rr_val
);
```

Comment: With this i get Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/content/80/11531780/html/postaje/arso.php on line 11

Comment: Did you declare `$spot` as an array before trying to assign values to it? Do you have `$spot = array();` near the start of your code?

Comment: Yes i did so. If i try just $spot[] = array( it works but i would still prefer to use first method

Comment: Interesting. According to the PHP docs for arrays, it says "Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type." Try doing a `print_r($meteo->domain_title);` to see if it's either an array or an object.

Comment: It is an object. Does that mean it cannot work this way? Do you know answer to the second part? How can i find out array number that has "ILIRSKA BISTRICA" inside ?

Comment: No. You'll need to use a value within that object instead of the object itself. What variables does the object have? Which of that object variables holds the value you want? Do `var_dump($meteo->domain_title)` this time as it seems to be more thorough.

Comment: I get object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { [0]=> string(7) "VELENJE" }. I would like to use "VELENJE"

Comment: Interesting. Try replacing `$meteo->domain_title` with `$meteo->0` and see if that works.

Comment: Nope. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in

Comment: According to the documentation, you're supposed to use `$meteo[0]` instead of `$meteo`. Try doing `print_r($meteo[0]);`. If you see a bunch of stuff, try using `$meteo[0]` instead of `$meteo` for the last part of your script. If that works, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: print_r($meteo[0]); did give results and using $meteo[0] works but as soon as i change  $spot[] = array( it stops working.

Comment: You changed the line to read `$spot[$meteo[0]->domain_title] = array(`, correct?

Comment: I tried $spot[$meteo[0]->domain_title] and also $spot[$meteo->domain_title]. Both times i get Illegal offset error

Comment: I manage to solve it with different aproach $xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_file($string)), 1);

$spot = array();

$meteos = $xml['metData']; 
foreach ($meteos as $meteo) {
    $spot[$meteo['domain_title']] = array(
        $meteo['domain_title'],.....  Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Save `$meteo` properties as array items.

```
foreach ($meteos as $meteo) {
    $spot[$meteo->domain_title] = array(
        $meteo->tsValid_issued, 
        $meteo->t, 
        $meteo->dd_icon,     
        $meteo->ff_val, 
        $meteo->ffmax_val, 
        $meteo->msl, 
        $meteo->rr_val, 
        $meteo->rr_val
    );
}
```